# Does the BlackBerry Java SDK support 1.5 syntax?

Tags: java, blackberry

Does the BlackBerry Java SDK support 1.5 syntax?  If not, has there been any hints that this is something that could be coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackberry is based on Java ME which is JRE 1.3. I would love Sun/Oracle to bring Java ME up to JRE 1.5 but I know of no effort to do that at present.

Comment: I believe I've seen that Java ME is to be replaced by Java SE, but I cannot locate it right now.  http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp does not immediately indicate this to be the case.

Comment: @Thorbjorn: We can only hope.  JME is the bane of my (professional) life.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use retroweaver to make a 1.4 version of your Java 5 code?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that the SDK is limited to 1.3, does retroweaver require 1.4?

Comment: According to http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/ it targets 1.4.  I don't believe there was a byte code format change between 1.3 and 1.4, so it might still be usable with careful usage (so you stay within the 1.3 capabilities).  Worth a try?

Comment: Retroweaver can target 1.3 also - I believe I tried one of my programs once, experimentally, just for kicks and it worked.  It was a reasonably complex app engine & http server.  See http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/guide/retroweaver-guide.html - there's a table of parameters and values: `target -> The target version as either "1.2", "1.3", or "1.4".`