# How to use jar of pure java project in blackberry project?

Tags: blackberry

I want to use java classes created in pure java project in my blackberry application. These classes are using file handling operations like object serialization,etc. I am using same jar file in android project and it is working. I want to use same jar in my blackberry project without making any changes in those classes. But in blackberry, in java.io package, all classes are not supported, like FileOutputStream, FileInputStream,etc. So is there any solution to this problem? Because I want to use same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [Does the BlackBerry Java SDK support 1.5 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389940/does-the-blackberry-java-sdk-support-1-5-syntax) and [Java version that RIM used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092759/java-version-that-rim-used)

Basically Blackberry is Java Micro Edition JRE 1.3 so you can't use features of pure Java there.

But there are custom implementations of serialization, see [Serialization via J2ME or BlackBerry APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449005/serialization-via-j2me-or-blackberry-apis) for example